# i want to delete particular single row by comparing four colum data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Right now i am using this query.

```
delete * from relay where username='xyz' , uname='admin' , password='123' , ip='10.1.1.80' and port = '80'.
```

but this query is not working.

i want to delete that row by forget this column values.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of commas use `AND` and remove the *.

```
delete from relay where username='xyz' AND uname='admin' AND password='123' AND ip='10.1.1.80' AND port = '80';
```

Comment: but i returns with 0 row delete

Comment: ya..but i have that row in my record and i want to delete it

Comment: Are you sure the values you are passing to the query do exist in the table?

Comment: in ip it does not compare point in ip that's why it returns with 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM relay WHERE username='xyz' , uname='admin' , password='123' , ip='10.1.1.80' and port = '80'
```

Comment: but i returns with 0 row delete

Comment: Then you can see if `SELECT` query is select the the row you want to delete. `SELECT *  FROM relay WHERE username='xyz' AND uname='admin' AND password='123' AND ip='10.1.1.80' AND port = '80'`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is slightly off.  You don't need to specify `*` after `DELETE` when deleting from a single table.  Also, your `WHERE` conditions should be separated by `AND`, not commas:

```
delete
from relay
where
    username = 'xyz' AND
    uname = 'admin'  AND
    password = '123' AND
    ip = '10.1.1.80' AND
    port = '80'
```

Note that if you were doing a delete join, then you would be mentioning either tables or aliases after the `DELETE` keyword.

Comment: Replace `delete` with `select *` and run it.  Do you get any results?  My guess is that your `WHERE` logic is wrong or you just don't have any matching data.

Comment: in ip it does not compare point in ip that's why it returns with 0 rows.

Comment: Well how are you storing your IP addresses?  Can you show sample data along with the column type being used?

Comment: i have used varchar(20) for my ip column

Comment: 50% there...now how are you storing `10.1.1.80` in that column?

Answer (score 0):

Your using `*` after delete. `*` not using in delete query.
And you are also using `,`. Use and operator instead of `,`.

This query may work for you.

```
Delete from relay where username='xyz' and uname='admin' and password='123' and ip='10.1.1.80' and port = '80';
```